# How to move a figure to an other page?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I make two pictures with TikZ in two figures at top of each secion.
I refer their position at the end of each section.
Can you suggest a way to move them arbitrarily?

### My problem is lables

They should make before using them.
Here is my entire code to show an example of a table (splited by lines) which forced me to locate the figure at the beginning of the section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

% and other necessary packages

\begin{document}
\section{جلسه اول}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[سوال اول و دوم]{\label{fig:J55VH}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [black] (.5,.5) rectangle (.75,.75);
  \foreach \x in {.125,.375,...,1.125}
    \foreach \y in {.125,.375,...,1.125}
      \draw (\x,\y) +(-.125,-.125) rectangle ++(.125,.125);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{جلسه اول(خانه‌های مشکی حذف شده‌اند.)}
\end{figure}

\begin{prob}
شکل
\ref{fig:J55VH}
را با تعداد کافی از مهره‌ی
\ref{fig:LP}
بپوشانید.
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
شکل
\ref{fig:J55VH}
را با تعداد کافی از مهره‌ی 
\ref{fig:3t1}
بپوشانید.
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should place them closer to where they're referenced... However, I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly.

Comment: The position of the `figure` environment does not depend on its contents (`tikz` in this case) so I think your question is just about floats not about `tikz`, it's not really clear where you want the figure to appear? In particular if you want it to come at the end of the section can you not just place the figure environment at the end rather than the start? Please always provide _complete_ (small) documents that demonstrate the issue, it is hard to comment on figure positioning just given a fragment.

Comment: Your edited question is perhaps less clear than the original. But note you nay refer to a label with `\ref`  _before_ the figure that defines the label, LaTeX will resolve the reference on the second run.

Comment: This is too confusing. MWE = Minimum Working Example, not Maximum Working Example.

Comment: You seemed to be worried about using labels before they are defined.  That is actually not a problem in LaTeX, you just have to compile the file twice.  LaTeX achieves this by writing the position of the label to an auxilliary file on the first run and then it reads that file early in the second run.

Comment: And slam dunk..

Comment: If you problem is the figure appearing before the section heading then use the option h.  I am guessing what you want here.  Here's the (your adjusted) code for inspection. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{testing}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [black] (.5,.5) rectangle (.75,.75);
  \foreach \x in {.125,.375,...,1.125}
    \foreach \y in {.125,.375,...,1.125}
      \draw (\x,\y) +(-.125,-.125) rectangle ++(.125,.125);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
testing\end{document}`